# File browser using Google Drive in PHP

Tags: php, file, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using this function to retrieve all of my Google drive files (as suggested by Google):

```
function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
  $result = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      $parameters['q'] = "'me' in owners";
      $parameters['fields'] = 'items(alternateLink, thumbnailLink, title, mimeType)';
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
      echo "<pre>";print_r($files);echo "</pre>";
      if(count($files)) {
          $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
          $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
      }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
     print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
     $pageToken = NULL;
  }
} while ($pageToken);
 return $result;
}
```

But this function only returns all of my files, without specifying the directories or their position.

Is there a function/method to do this, to retrieve the same information but exploring it folder by folder starting by root and exploring them?

Comment: You can see that it's running in a loop. Have you checked the result after a single iteration of the code?

Comment: No. If you want that, you'll need to write it yourself. When using drive, you must always remember that "folders" are really "labels", not "containers"